Please delete the tags [de] and [s]
I was tagging some question, and my IME was in the state for entering Chinese, and I mistyped these letters.
At the same time, it seems [cryptographic] and [chess] are irrelevant for us, delete them as well?

This is done (by mods and users alike) by editing the relevant questions to remove the tag. The tags with no questions attached to them are then cleaned up daily. I've done this for the [cryptographic] and [chess] tags, but don't see the [de] and [s] tags (if you removed them yourself, it is likely the system has cleaned them up by now).
